# updateSearchResults() not getting called

Tags: search, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I have read similar problems and solutions on SO. But none seems to solve my problem. I am using Custom Search Controller and Custom Search Bar and **func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)** is not getting called.

```
    var customSearchController: CustomSearchViewController!
```

CustomSearchViewController: In ViewDidLoad()

```
customSearchController = CustomSearchViewController(searchResultsController: ***nil***, searchBarFrame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: searchTableView.frame.size.width, height: 44.0), searchBarFont: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16.0)!, searchBarTextColor: UIColor.purple, searchBarTintColor: UIColor.white)

customSearchController.searchResultsUpdater  = self
customSearchController.definesPresentationContext = true
customSearchController.customSearchBar.placeholder = "What are you looking for?"
customSearchController.customSearchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
customSearchController.customSearchBar.sizeToFit()
customSearchController.customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
customSearchController.customSearchBar.showsCancelButton = true
customSearchController.customSearchBar.delegate = self
```

Not getting called: :(

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filtered.removeAll()
    filtered = searchArray.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: customSearchController.customSearchBar.text!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    self.searchTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchResultsUpdating not being called in UISearchController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769598/searchresultsupdating-not-being-called-in-uisearchcontroller)

Answer (score 11):

After struggling for hours, I was able to solve it by using:
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) - UISearchBarDelegate delegate method.

instead of updateSearchResults() - UISearchResultsUpdating delegate method

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 7):

I had to declare `UISearchController` instance within the class scope. See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781890/1511978

Previously I had declared it within the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Yep of course! Otherwise it gets deallocated once it goes out of scope

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you did not set this:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

Make sure this is the last command to avoid getting errors. At least this did the job for me.

Comment: This is not the answer...see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781890/1511978

Answer (score 0):

But maybe your problem was that you call that:

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

Instead, you should do that:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Comment: Can you provide a reason, why this would help?

Comment: Actually, I tried the two cases and I find that the second one works but the first one does not.

Comment: I think the reason is that, in the first case the search controller is not added to the view (just the searchBar) so I can not listen to its changes so the method 'updateSearchResults' will not called.