# SearchResultsUpdating not being called in UISearchController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchcontroller

I'm working with UISearchController in Xamarin.Ios and everything works fine but when I start typing, the SearchhResultUpdating method is not override is not firing. It works sometimes and doesn't somw other times but now it doesn't work at all.

Here's the SearchResultsUpdating Class:

```
class SearchResult : UISearchResultsUpdating
{
    public event Action<string> UpdateSearchResults = delegate { };

    public override void UpdateSearchResultsForSearchController(UISearchController searchController)
    {

        this.UpdateSearchResults(searchController.SearchBar.Text);
    }
}
```

and Here's when I used it:

```
 var searchresult = new SearchResult();
 searchresult.UpdateSearchResults += searchResultsController.Search;
 var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController) { SearchResultsUpdater = searchresult };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You should make `searchController` as `global variable` .

If you do that , it won't release and keep in its life circle , and fire that method in `UISearchResultsUpdating`

Refer to this [Demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/MapDemo/)

Comment: Wow. You sir are a life saver. Setting the searchcontroller as a global variable fixed it. Thanks

Comment: You also can store it in container where define your search result view, but not in search result view (maybe) :)