# updateSearchResults function is not being called when searchBar is touched

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

The `updateSearchResults` function isn't getting called in my view table controller view for some reason and I don't know why? I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41561286/12647189) but it's nothing similar to mine and I don't want to use the `textDidChange` function.

I have this view `SearchViewController` where it has a search bar at the top and it will have a collection view below it. (Making instagrams explore page). Once the search bar has been tapped, it should display view `SearchTableViewController` which shows the results of the search query in a table view.

This is my code:

SearchViewController (the main view):

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let searchResultsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultsViewController") as? SearchTableViewController else { return}

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsViewController)

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsViewController


    view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
}
```

SearchTableViewController (the view that gets displayed with the results):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SearchTableViewController: UIViewController {

let languages = ["Mandarin Chinese", "English", "Hindustani", "Spanish", "Arabic", "Malay", "Russian", "Bengali", "Portuguese", "French", "Hausa", "Punjabi", "German", "Japanese", "Persian", "Swahili", "Telugu", "Javanese", "Wu Chinese", "Korean"]
var searchResults: [String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
}

}

extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("typing")
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    searchResults = languages.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}

extension SearchTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath)

    let language = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = language
    return cell
}
}
```

the `updateSearchResults` in the `extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating` isn't being called which I think is the cause of the table view with the search results not loading the search query data?

Comment: Are you sure your `searchController` is being setup properly?

Comment: @koen what would be the correct way? I assume that's all perfectly fine, so yes.

Comment: Don't assume, you won't know if you don't check it. I'd s through `viewDidLoad` and see if `searchController` and `searchResultsViewController` get  instantiated. There is also a good tutorial on Ray Wenderlich showing all the needed steps.

Comment: @koen how would I check that and could you point me towards this' 'tutorial'

Comment: First of all, make sure that they are not nil using the debugger or print statements.This is pretty basic stuff. And you can find the tutorial and many more if you just search for `uisearchcontroller tutorial`.

Comment: @koen oh no I know that, I've already done that; nothing is nil, it's just when I print in the function `updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the assignment to the navigation controller too. Even if you're showing the search results on another screen you still need to add it:

```
navigationItem.searchController = theSearchControllerYouInstantiated
```